# Программа неожиданно завершилась

Tags: c++, qt

При запуске программы выводится ошибка. Никаких логов ничего нет в консоли.  Делаю get-запрос к серверу и все.
https://github.com/Radzhab/QTparser/tree/master/QTparser

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   ui->pushButton->setText("Запуск с рабочего компа");
}
```

//////////////////////////////

```
#include "httphelper.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QEventLoop>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QObject>

HttpHelper::HttpHelper()
{

}

void HttpHelper::GetHtml()
{
    QNetworkAccessManager manager;

    QNetworkRequest request(QUrl("http://qt-project.org"));
    request.setAttribute(QNetworkRequest::FollowRedirectsAttribute, true);

    QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(request);

    QEventLoop event;
    connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
    event.exec();

    QString html = response->readAll(); // Source should be stored here
}
```

Comment: Выложите весь проект на гитхаб или еще куда. Угадайка по обрывкам исходников - пустая трата времени.

Comment: https://github.com/Radzhab/QTparser/tree/master/QTparser

Comment: кресты, это для настоящих бородатых мужиков! )

Comment: что за кресты?)

Comment: "*Никаких логов ничего нет в консоли*" - а отладчик зачем изобрели?

Comment: @Radzhab, так называют c++

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде никаких проблем нет - у меня все собралось и запустилось.

Попробуйте удалить каталог сборки - тот, который `build_...`.

Единственная потенциальная проблема - не следует писать в исходниках сообщения на русском языке, для этого есть инструменты локализации - Qt Linguist.